# Declare a constants from user input

Tags: java

I am not sure if this is even the correct question to ask so I will just explain what I am trying to do. I am just learning Java and I have to write a simple program to encrypt and decrypt a message by just shifting each letter by a certain number. I have to have three classes, one which statically encrypts, statically decrypts, and the main which tests each and takes all the user input. What I don't fully understand is that I have to assign the key to a constant. This is the basic structure:

```
public class Decryptor{
    public static void decrypt(String message, String[] alphabet, int shiftKey){
        //decrypt the message
    }

    public static String[] generateCypherAlphabet(String[] alphabet, int shiftKey){
        // generate a cipher alphabet based on the key...which is somehow a constant
    }
}

public class Encryptor{
    public static void encrypt(String message, String[] alphabet, int shiftKey){
        //encrypt the message
    }

    public static String[] generateCypherAlphabet(String[] alphabet, int shiftKey){
        // generate a cipher alphabet based on the key...which is somehow a constant
    }
}

class Tester{
    private static final String[] ALPHABET = new String[26];

    public static void generateAlphabet(){
        // populate the constant ALPHABET
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        // get some user input
        // either decrypt or encrypt the message based on the key
        // if the key is user dependant, how could it be a constant?
    }
}
```

Comment: One one hand, data being user-input and constant are mutually exclusive. But on the other hand, Java has no constants. It only has `static final` variables which are similar in spirit but have some fundamental differences. Are you sure you aren't misunderstanding your instructions? When you do, it is impossible to help you unless you quote them.

Comment: @christopher The String[] is final, each object in it is not. (meaning, you can manipulate the same array, but not bind a new array to this variable)

Comment: @amit right you are! Deleted.

Answer (score 0):

When using `final` with a primitive datatype, it's value can only be set once and not be changed anymore.

If using it with a parameter, it will not allow your function to change the value:

```
public static void decrypt(String message, String[] alphabet, final int shiftKey){
    //In this scope, shiftKey is constant. It cannot be changed.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you are being asked to do is to have the Tester class contain a constant key value, which it just passes to the Decryptor and Encryptor methods.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you could just put the line (or something similar):

```
final static MY_CONSTANT = scannerObject.nextInt();
```

right into your main method. It does seem strange to have a constant dependent on user input, but if you have different files for the classes, there would be no need for the constant to be declared globally in your main class, because it would be passed to the encrypt and decrypt classes within the main method.

Answer (score 0):

Your final modifier for variable *ALPHABET* makes it impossible to redefine the pointer to the array that it was initialised with, but it doesn't prohibit from changing the String values inside the array.

Answer (score 0):

While you cannot change the array stored in `ALPHABET`, you can change each object in it.

You should set `ALPHABET[i]` to the relevant `String` object that should be referred by this value of `i`.

This should probably be done in `generateAlphabet()` according to your task's logic.

As a side note - using so many `static` methods and variables is usually a bad practice, and takes all the edge out of object oriented programming.